# Unable to read code in android java class

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In my project one android activity have some unexpected error.My original code in both Java class and in XML file has been replaced by some anonymous text I am unable to understand where does it comes from. 
In my project structure that class also have some other icon type then rest of the other classes.

Here is the picture below :

[image: Error]

Someone please let me know why this kind of problem is occuring.

**THANKS**

Comment: close this project and import it again from file - new - import project.

Comment: it seems you have unintentionally pasted this text from somewhere

Comment: totally wrong code

Comment: @Abdul Waheed no i didn't paste the code it was working fine till yesterday but today when i launched android studio it showed up this kind of error.

Comment: try clean and rebuild project

Comment: @Radesh this code replaced my original code in both java as well as xml file.

Comment: try to recover from histroy in android studio

Comment: @AbdulWaheed how to recover please let me know.

Comment: in android studio click on vcs and go for the local history this is the last option you have.

Comment: What if i delete .idea amd .iml file and import it again will it solve my problem.

Comment: @Digvijay probably deleting the intellij files might but it depends on if your local code base is already corrupted. Are you using git or any other form of version control? If so you might want to consider rolling back to the previous version if deleting the .idea and .iml files dont work.

Comment: @cokeby190 currently i m not using git or any other version control.

Comment: @Digvijay perhaps you might to consider using a form of version control for the future? For the current situation though, have you tried deleting .idea and .iml files? Does it work?

Comment: @cokeby190 I simply re-imported my project and it resolved problem.BTW thanks for help.

Comment: @Digvijay great to hear that!